How to Use Existing VPC and Subnet to Launch a New EC2 Instance with CloudFormation?
I'm trying to launch a new EC2 instance using AWS CloudFormation, but I want to use my existing VPC and subnets instead of creating new ones. I have the VPC ID and subnet IDs that I want to use, but I'm not sure how to reference these existing resources in my CloudFormation template.
Here are the details of what I'm trying to achieve:
Use an existing VPC (e.g., vpc-0123456789abcdef0).
Use an existing subnet (e.g., subnet-0123456789abcdef0) within the specified VPC.
Create a new EC2 instance in the specified subnet.
Create a new security group within the existing VPC.
I know how to create a VPC and subnets within a CloudFormation template, but I'm not sure how to reference existing ones. Here's what I have so far:
Parameters:   
  VpcId:
    Description: The ID of the existing VPC
    Type: String
    Default: "vpc-0123456789abcdef0"
  SubnetId1:
    Description: The ID of the existing subnet where the instance will be launched
    Type: String
    Default: "subnet-0123456789abcdef0"

Resources:
  NewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0abcdef1234567890
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId1
          DeviceIndex: 0
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref SecurityGroup
          DeleteOnTermination: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: NewEC2Instance

  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow SSH and HTTP access
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

Outputs:   EC2InstanceId:
    Description: The ID of the new EC2 instance
    Value: !Ref NewEC2Instance   SecurityGroupId:
    Description: The ID of the security group
    Value: !Ref SecurityGroup

Is this the correct way to reference existing VPC and subnets, or is there a better approach using the name of the existing resources instead assigning direct value? Any help would be appreciated!

See Referencing Parameters on: Parameters - AWS CloudFormation

You may use the below cloudformation parameters.
Parameters:
  AssociatedVPC:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>
    Description: Ids of the VPC to be associated with the Subnet
  AssociatedSubnet:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Ids of the the Subnet

